# Execute asynchronous read in parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I found it useful to execute multiple reads in parallel using a set of my extension methods for `TaskFactory`, which could be used as:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var (r1, r2, r3, r4) = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        Read1Async, Read2Async, Read3Async, Read4Async);

    async Task<int> Read1Async() => /* cut as not relevant */;
    async Task<string> Read2Async() => /* cut as not relevant */;
    async Task<long> Read3Async() => /* cut as not relevant */;
    async Task<double[]> Read4Async() => /* cut as not relevant */;
}
```

The actual helper code is:

```
public static class TaskFactoryExtensions
{
    public async static Task<(T1, T2)> StartNew<T1, T2>(
        this TaskFactory taskFactory,
        Func<Task<T1>> action1,
        Func<Task<T2>> action2)
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(action1);
        var task2 = Task.Run(action2);            
        return (await task1, await task2);
    }

    public async static Task<(T1, T2, T3)> StartNew<T1, T2, T3>(
        this TaskFactory taskFactory,
        Func<Task<T1>> action1,
        Func<Task<T2>> action2,
        Func<Task<T3>> action3)
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(action1);
        var task2 = Task.Run(action2);
        var task3 = Task.Run(action3);            
        return (await task1, await task2, await task3);
    }

    public async static Task<(T1, T2, T3, T4)> StartNew<T1, T2, T3, T4>(
        this TaskFactory taskFactory,
        Func<Task<T1>> action1,
        Func<Task<T2>> action2,
        Func<Task<T3>> action3,
        Func<Task<T4>> action4)
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(action1);
        var task2 = Task.Run(action2);
        var task3 = Task.Run(action3);
        var task4 = Task.Run(action4);
        return (await task1, await task2, await task3, await task4);
    }
}
```

It just saves on typing...

Comment: I just came across in the VTC queue, LCC.

Comment: Would `Task.WaitAll` work here? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @alexyorke Nope, you will not get the results. And only `Task` or `Task<T[]>` could be returned from `Task.WhenAll()`. Here we could work with multiple datatypes being returned as a tuple in a single line of code.

Comment: @alexyorke We could use it in the extension method implementation, but it adds one extra line without helping anyhow and could be dangerous (a blocking call). TPL was never been updated after tuple introduction, so we are alone in making helpers like that :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin thank you for the clarification; I will have to read up on the documentation

Comment: that is strange to use separate thread for async read  operation ...

Comment: @Disappointed It is a very generic mechanism. `Task.Run` usage allows to keep a preexisting `Task.Factory.StartNew` semantics. Throwing an exception from a synchronous part of `Read2Async` (before the very first `await`) will otherwise prevent `Read3Async` and `Read4Async` invocation and unwind the stack in a situation with no `await` like `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Read1Async, Read2Async)` - not what one would expect from `StartNew`.